# vmware-vdiskmanager is not present in my system

Tags: 12.04, vmware, disk

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to expand size allocated to Linux virtual machine, but I'm not able to find `vmware-vdiskmanager` or any package that installs `vmware-vdiskmanager`. Can anyone please tell me how to install `vmware-vdiskmanager` or link to download it...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far I as know `vmware-vdiskmanager` is a utility that comes bundled with VMware Fusion and VMware Workstation.

I found a 32bits version *1023856-vdiskmanager-linux.7.0.1.zip* available for download [here on kb.vmware.com](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/viewAttachment.do?attachID=1023856-vdiskmanager-linux.7.0.1.zip&documentID=1023856) (direct link from the [Attachments section](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023856)).

[Source](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/NovaVMware/DeveloperGuide#3._vmware-vdiskmanager)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the 32bit version available for download here on kb.vmware.com from the [Attachments section](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023856).

- Download and unzip the *1023856-vdiskmanager-linux-7.0.1.zip* file
- Expand the compressed file, and rename it to `vmware-vdiskmanager`
- Copy the vmware-vdiskmanager file to `/usr/bin/`
- give it executable rights

this will automate the installation:

```
cd /tmp/
wget http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/viewAttachment.do?attachID=1023856-vdiskmanager-linux.7.0.1.zip&documentID=1023856
unp 1023856-vdiskmanager-linux-7.0.1.zip
mv 1023856-vmware-vdiskmanager-linux.7.0.1 /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager
chmod +x /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager
```

To use it run for example compress a vm with this command:

```
/usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager -k ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/<virtual disk.vmdk>
```

Answer (score 2):

Needed the same for an ubuntu 18.04 workstation with vmware-player installed (not part of the bundle).

Downloaded the VDDK (Virtual Disk Development Kit) v7.0 from here:
https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/7.0/vddk (needed my vmware account credentials to do so.)

tar -xzvf VMware-vix-disklib-7.0.0-15832853.x86_64.tar.gz
./vmware-vix-disklib-distrib/bin64/vmware-vdiskmanager

My vmware-player was installed in /usr/lib/vmware/, so I suggest you untar the download in /usr/lib/ which will result in the necessary parts being at /usr/lib/vmware-vix-disklib-distrib

Answer (score 1):

The disk manager download suggested by Sylvain is dependent on OpenSSL. If you don't have it installed you will get an error message as follows:

> SSLLoadSharedLibrary: Failed to load library libeay32.dll

OpenSSL is available from here: http://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html

Downloading and installing OpenSSL resolves this issue.

Note: I have realised that the OpenSSL dlls are present in the VMware Player installation directory. If the tool is copied into the VMware player directory and executed from there the installation of OpenSSL is unnecessary.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! For Windows like you said just copy the `vmware-vdiskmanager` to the VMWare Player Installation directory and run it from there. Downloading the copying the libeay32.dll into the folder along with `vmware-vdiskmanager` does not work, it needs to run from the VMWare Player installation directory